# How to type user name on a pop up window using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, pyautogui

I have a task to accomplish that is:

1. Open a web page that is https://www.aetna.com/aqc

   2. Now I need to type user name and password in the pop up.
   3. Click Ok

I tried using pyautogui package write function but that didn't worked for me. Also I tried to get the element ID of the fields using XPath and that also didn't worked.

Please suggest a solution for it in Python3

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Why didn't it worked for you? What was the core of the problem?

Comment: Hi @akash-pratap-singh if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of popup is not a normal popup. it is a ["http authentication"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).
you can use the requests package to insert the data:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

more info [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/)